# Use js variable for html form that will be used in php query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have index.php page where data is pulled from database and displayed as simple table (each row can be selected with my js script).

[image]

I have js script which does all selection and stores ID number from the table into the js variable.

```
$(function() {

/* Get all rows from table but not the first one 
 * that includes headers. */
var rows = $('tr').not(':first');

/* Create 'click' event handler for rows */
rows.on('click', function(e) {

    /* Get current row */
        var row = $(this);

    /* highlights the row*/ 
        rows.removeClass('highlight');
        row.addClass('highlight');

    /*outputs the ID of the selected row to rowID variable*/
        var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");
        var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html();
        var rowID=col1;


  });

});
```

I have another dbUpdate.php script which has html form and php query.

```
 if( !$_POST["e1"] ){

    $e1Error = "Please enter value <br>";
} else {    
    $e1 = validateFormData ( $_POST["e1"] );
}

if( !$_POST["rowID"] ){

    $rowID = validateFormData ( $_POST["rowID"] );
}

// check variable has data
if( $e1 && $rowID ) {
    $query = "UPDATE athletes SET e1 = ($e1) WHERE id = ($rowID) ";
```

and here is the html form

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ); ?>" method="post">
            <small class="text-danger">* <?php echo $e1Error; ?></small>
            <input type="text" placeholder="e1" name="e1"><br><br>
            <input type="hidden" id="rowID1" name="rowID" value=""/>
```

My aim is to get that ID number from js variable rowID and store it in my dbUpdate.php form (name="rowID") when i select one of the rows in my html table (shown in the picture).

Comment: And? Where do you get the `rowID` value? Are you reading it out (it doesn't appear so, in your javascript)?  Are you then posting it to the second page?

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet rowID comes from  var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html(); Thats where I am stuck, I dont know the mechanics of how to post that rowID to other page

Comment: You're going to have to either have a form with a hidden input and post that, or you're going to have to use something like ajax to post it, or you're going to have to navigate to a url with that parameter as part of the query string.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet could you link me to some examples please that would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an `ajax` example (using jQuery syntax, since that's what it looks like you're using):

```
        rows.on('click', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/dbUpdate.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { rowID: $(rowID).val() },
                cache: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Woot!');
                }
                , error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }
            });
        });
```

Now, obviously, that's going to just pull the return back into your success function.  If you're trying to have your `dbUpdate.php` page return html to the client, that's a different story.  What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Basically it will work as admin > user system. Admin selects  the row and then user will assign the e1 value using the form in dbUpdate.php, but I just realised how stupid I am... I need to store that rowID value in database first in order for the user to pull

Comment: Glad you found it! Sometimes talking it through helps you to see the answer, even when it's not at all related, eh? :)